# CSS background property confusion?

Tags: html, css, center

I cant find why center/cover is used in this code.

What property is the center referring to. 
I know this is really basic but please help me by giving an answer as its stopping me from continuing to learn.

```
     background: url('img/page-bg.png') no-repeat center center/cover;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `center` values are referring to `background-position` (X and Y) and `cover` is the value for the property `background-size`. What's happening here is `center center` is centering the image both horizontally and vertically. `cover` is scaling the image to take up the whole screen, with no empty space. Please see below for details.

The `background` property is shorthand CSS and sets multiple styles at once. Check the docs at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

> The background shorthand CSS property sets all background style properties at once, such as color, image, origin and size, or repeat method.

The property that `center/cover` is referring to is `background-position` and `background-size`:

> The `<bg-size>` value may only be included immediately after `<position>`, separated with the `/` character, like this: `center/80%`.

The value `cover` scales the image as large as possible without stretching and will crop so that no empty space remains.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it’s not too dissimilar from applying margin: 0 auto on other elements. Backgrounds of elements have some special properties to help with the location as it’s rendered.
https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_background-position.asp

The default is top left of the parent element that it is in. So you can apply the location to override that default.